# What is the best software to create photorealistic worlds?

Tags: software-recommendations

What is the best software to create photorealistic worlds?

Comment: It’s utterly unclear, what the first two sentences are supposed to mean

Comment: You question is rather unclear: what do mean by "realizing [...] worlds" ? Are you interesting in realizing the geographic of it ? Or particular sceneries ? Or maybe maps ?

Comment: Google Earth and Bing Maps.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as off topic: there is ample precedence for [tag:software-recommendations] questions being on topic, and only "software that doesn't directly relate to worldbuilding" is [off topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I feel that this question needs work, but it's not categorically off topic.

Answer (score 6):

- If you want photorealism and do not care about mapping an entire globe, try [World Machine](https://www.world-machine.com/) (Paid, demo available)
- If you want a good looking globe but don't much care about realism, you can try using [Fractal Terrains](https://www.profantasy.com/products/ft.asp) (Paid), combine with [Wilbur](http://www.fracterra.com/wilbur.html) (Free) for better results.
- If you want a professional-looking result and are willing to spend the time to learn professional-level software, you could use [Terragen](https://planetside.co.uk/) (Free for non-commercial)

All three software packages are for the procedural creation of terrain and semi-realistic to photorealistic rendering.